# Pandas read '\0' in CSV column as NULL character and print as Unicode in JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a csv with one columns has `'\0'` value. I want to print it in json as `\u0000` value. I used pandas `read_csv` and set the dtypes of the column as `str` to read the file. When I print it to json, it printed as `\\0`, which is `\0` with the backslash escaped.

How can I properly read it as NULL character and print it as unicode `\u0000`?

This is the csv example

```
id,data,timestamp
1,\0,2018-03-17 03:12:58
2,\0,2018-03-19 09:00:40
3,\0,2018-03-19 09:26:05
```

The output that I expect

```
{ "id": 1, "data": "\u0000", "timestamp":"2018-03-17T03:12:58.000Z"}
{ "id": 2, "data": "\u0000", "timestamp":"2018-03-19T09:00:40.000Z"}
{ "id": 3, "data": "\u0000", "timestamp":"2018-03-19T09:26:05.000Z"}
```

How I read it using pandas

```
csvfile = open('somefile.csv', 'r')

col_names = ['id', 'data']
dtypes = { 'data': str }
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, names=col_names, dtype=dtypes)
```

And how I write it to json

```
jsonfile = open('somefile.json', 'w')
df.to_json(jsonfile, orient='records', lines=True, date_format='iso')
```

Comment: Are you only using Pandas to read the csv and convert to JSON?  Are you using the Dataframe for anything else?

Comment: @ZakiIndra if an answer resolves your problem, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: (Wow, that was fast :-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\0` is not a valid representation of a null byte in CSV. Instead, it expects a literal null byte (which is okay since the parser only looks for the specified delimiters to separate the stream into fields).

To process a file with escape sequences, you can specify [`encoding='unicode_escape'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs#python-specific-encodings) in `pd.read_csv()`. This encoding will decode the escape sequence into a literal null character.